# Add data using the :data-obj directive after async function finishes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add some data to the DOM using the :data-obj directive. However, I want to delay this process until an asynchronous function has completed. Unfortunately, every time I attempt this, it only adds the promise. I've tried awaiting the response in the computed method, but still got back a promise and eslint hates it.  Any ideas?

```
<template>
  <div
    class="test-data"
    :data-obj="getData()"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'compName',
  components: {
    ...,
  },
  props: {
   ...
  },

  setup(props) {
   
    /**
   * Get data from api
   */
    function getTestData() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const query = "theThingsINeed"
        fetch(query).then((resp) => {
          resolve(resp);
        });
      });
    }


    const getdata = async () => {
      const data = await getTestData();
      return JSON.stringify(data);
     
    };

    return {
      getdata,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using the mounted method and my function there.

```
<template>
  <div
    class="test-data"
    :data-obj="getData()"
  />
</template>
...
data() {
    return {
      data: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.testData = async () => {
      const data = await this.getTestData();
      this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    };
    this.testData();
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Get data from api
     */
    getTestData() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const query = "theThingsINeed"
        fetch(query).then((resp) => {
          resolve(resp);
          return resp;
        });
      });
    },
```